# Простая программа не компилируется на c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуется вывести элементы стека, проект не хочет собираться, исходный код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

void print_stack(stack<int>& s) {
    vector<int> tmp;
    while (!s.empty()) {
        tmp.push_back(s.top());
        s.pop();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.size(); i++) {
        cout << tmp[i] << "\n";
    }
}

typedef long long ll;
int main()
{
    stack<int> a;
    a.push(5);
    a.push(4);
    a.push(3);
    print_stack(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: В вашем случае — вы написали консольное приложение, а собираете его как оконное.